# Function to create a variable

Tags: pandas, function

I have a database with 4 columns : cur_sales_id, sales, rate_sales and Taux_change.
I've created the following variable to get the variation rate for each of my data :

```
df["Ecart_mref"]= round(((df.sales / df.rate_sales - df.sales * df.Taux_change)/ df.sales * df.Taux_change * 100))
```

I would like to create a new variable such that when cur_sales_id = 2 the value is equal to its rate of change. So I created this function :

```
def fun(row):
  if row['cur_sales_id'] == 2:  
    val = df.Ecart_mref
  else:
    val = None
  return val
df['fun'] = df.apply(fun, axis=1)
```

Except that when I try to do so, the new variable "fun" doesn't give me just one value each time, but all values, as below :

```
    0                                                   None
    1      [-6.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, -6....
    2      [-6.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, -6....
    3      [-6.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, -6....
    4      [-6.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, -6....
```

Thanks to those who will read it

Answer (score 1):

```
def fun(row):
  if row['cur_sales_id'] == 2:  # (1)
    val = df.Ecart_mref # (2)
  else:
    val = None
  return val
df['fun'] = df.apply(fun, axis=1)
```

(2) You're returning the full column by using df.col_name. Look how at (1) you made a condition on the row value.

The same way you didnt use df["cur_sales_id"] == 2 in (1), you should use `val = row["Ecart_mref"]` in (2).